# setInterval reset loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created the following function to countdown from 5 to 0, but it doesnt restart the countdown at 0. What's my fail?

JS:

```
var cc = 5;
var myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 1000);

function myFn() {
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = -- cc;

  if (cc == 0) {
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 1000);
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="counter">5</span>
```

Comment: the problem is that your `var cc` is not reset to 5.

Comment: You need to reset cc as well

if (cc == 0){
clearInterval(myTimer);
cc = 5;
myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 1000)
}

Comment: Aaaaah, ok, thx!

Comment: Just a pointer, but you should not have space here `-- cc`

Comment: Ouh, yes, thx @Rajesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are clearing interval and setting another one with the same callback, but you are never restoring the value of `cc` variable!

```js
var cc = 5;
var myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 1000);

function myFn() {
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML= --cc;

  if (cc == 0) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    cc = 5;
    myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 1000);
  }

}
```

```html
Countdown: <span id="counter">5</span>
```

Comment: Yes, what a brainbug!! ;) Sorry for that and thanks for support!

Answer (score 2):

```
var cnt = 5;
var myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 1000);

function myFn() {
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML= --cnt;

  if (cnt == 0) {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    cnt= 5;
    myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 1000);
  }

}



Counter: <span id="counter">5</span>
```